# How to enable Intel Virtualization if setting not found in BIOS but supported by CPU

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I have the following CPU: http://ark.intel.com/products/75119

It supports Intel Virtualization, but it is disabled according to Intel software utility.

How can I enable Intel Virtualization, if the setting is not available in BIOS ?

Is there some way of enabling it by means of software ?

Comment: If an option is not offered you won't be able to enable it.

Comment: Is there a BIOS update for your motherboard?

Comment: Add information about mobo model and it current BIOS version.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that Intel virtualization cannot be enabled in your BIOS? I've seen some weird menu placements for its toggle.

Comment: I'm a very experienced BIOS-user. I've checked every single setting in BIOS. You are only allowable to change Intel Rapid Storage and Boot Priority toghether with time/date and Network card.

Answer (score 2):

Intel CPUs are designed to allow virtualization to be disabled and unable to be turned back on until the next physical power cycle, likely for security reasons (i.e. a bootkit could theoretically install a malicious hypervisor).  I'm not sure of the exact reason why some BIOSes don't allow virtualization to be enabled.

You will need to upgrade your BIOS to a version that allows you to change the setting if the manufacturer has chosen to do this, or scour the Internet for a hacked BIOS, if it exists, that is modified to allow you change this setting.  You will have to do searching on your own for such a BIOS as I've never went that route with any system I have.