# How to install Intel Virtualization Technology?

Tags: windows, cpu, qemu, hardware-virtualization

CPU: [Intel® Core™ i7-4710MQ Processor](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/78931/intel-core-i7-4710mq-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-50-ghz.html)

Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC

Hyper-V:

[image: Hyper-V]

When I install Virtualization Technology driver got below:

[image: haxm]

I check the BIOS, and there don't have the option for Virtualization Technology.
BTW I want to make QEMU run faster. If any other way for acceleration also helps me.

Comment: Intel Virtualization Technology is enable in the firmware.  It isn't something you can install or enable from within Windows.  If your unable to enable it within the firmware configuration then your system simply does not support VT-x despite you CPU supporting it.

Comment: @Ramhound Hi, I checked the CPU specification, There was a link in my question. i7-4710MQ Processor supposes support the VT-x.

Comment: While CPU supports VT-x (which I said was the case in my original comment), you cannot enable it within your firmware, which means your hardware does not support it.  Since you cannot enable VT-x within the firmware, there is no way to enable hardware virtualization on your hardware, your situation is not uncommon with OEM hardware.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable Intel Virtualization if setting not found in BIOS but supported by CPU](https://superuser.com/questions/757904/how-to-enable-intel-virtualization-if-setting-not-found-in-bios-but-supported-by) or [this](https://superuser.com/questions/865116/i-cannot-find-my-vt-x-in-my-bios) or [this](https://superuser.com/questions/911257/does-vt-x-really-need-bios-support/911262#911262)

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks! Look like that is what I wanna, Let me try to update the BIOS.